# How to understand GM_xmlhttpRequest parameter "binary"

Tags: gm-xmlhttprequest

I tested below code:

`GM_xmlhttpRequest({
                method: 'POST',
                url: "some url",
                data: "a1b2",
                binary: false});

GM_xmlhttpRequest({
                method: 'POST',
                url: "some url",
                data: "a1b2",
                binary: true});`

I used Fiddler to check what's really send. but seems the two code sent same raw data by http.
I also tested the code below

GM_xmlhttpRequest({
                method: 'POST',
                url: "some url",
                data: new Blob([1,2,3]),
                binary: false});

GM_xmlhttpRequest({
                method: 'POST',
                url: "some url",
                data: new Blob([1,2,3]),
                binary: true});

but the two code send identical raw data

Comment: What browser version?  What Tampermonkey/Greasemonkey/Violentmonkey version?

Comment: chrome 71.0.3578.98, tampermonkey 4.8